# How can I know if I have scrolled past a certain child of ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swiftui

In SwiftUI, how can I know if I a child of a ScrollView is no longer visible because it has been scrolled out of the visible area?

For example,

```
ScrollView {
  Text("A")
  Text("B")
  // ..
  Text("Z")
}
```

How can I know that "A" is no longer visible?

Comment: How did you try?

Comment: I looked at ScrollViewReader, but I am having a hard time understanding if that is useful from the documentation.  It seems like that only lets me to move to some area of the ScrollView

Comment: Hey I figured it out @Asperi, I use a LazyVStack as child of ScrollView, and he is the parent of the childs, and I can use .onDisappear :D